# Angular 2 - Toggle/change div to set first position

Tags: angular, toggle

[image]

on clicking on the arrow(button), that image should be set as the primary image, and that value should effect in the backend too.

i have no idea of doing this, tried dragula, but that's not sufficient for me

Code given below is how the div is placed

```
........
  <li>
              <div class="col-xs-12 dishkya">
                <div class="file-up">
                  <input type="file" class="form-control filed" placeholder="Name" (change)="onFileChange($event,shopId)" #fileInput >
                  <img  [src]="getShopImageURL((shopDetail | async)?.main_image)" class="add-pht">
                  <!-- <a class="deleteit"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> -->
                  </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="col-xs-4 dishkya">
                <div class="file-up">
                 <input type="file" class="form-control filed" placeholder="Name"  (change)="SecondFileChange($event,shopId)" #fileInput >
                  <img  [src]="getShopImageURL((shopDetail | async)?.image_one)" class="add-pht">
                  <!-- <a class="deleteit"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> -->
                  </div>
              </div>
            </li>

...........
```

the way which the image uploaded is

```
    private imageUpload: any = {
         "upload":""
     };
     private SecondimageUpload: any = {
          "upload":""
      };
...............
...............

onFileChange(event,shopId) {
    var self = this;
    if(event.target.files.length > 0) {
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      this.fileName = file.name;
      this.imageUpload['upload'] = this.fileName;
      this.form.get('upload').setValue(file);

    }
    self.check_publish_status = true;
    this.imageUpload['upload'] = this.fileName;
    const formModel = this.prepareSave();
    var body = formModel;
..................
     return this.http.post(url, body, options)
          .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
          .subscribe(
              data => {
self.fetchShopData();
        )
    ........................
    ........................
```

please provide an idea to achieve this.

Comment: You can simply map the images you want to an array. 0 being the main image and the rest after that. That way you can easily change the order of the images.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply, the image upload is been already done in the way , i have just added above. is it still possible to map in to an array

Comment: it is a sample of stackBitz, you can refere this. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bfr2ft

Answer (score 0):

The best way is on clicking arrow button call your Rest API's for backend and set your primary Image there and then after success tries to get same from the backend and render the images position accordingly.

Comment: thank you for your reply, all images is been already set,as like i added above(question edited).